# How to create an array from a MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a HTML search form made with PHP that connects to a MySQL database, finds a table with columns and rows and then displays this data with an echo under the table.

```sql
$output = "Document ID: ".$results['id']."<br><a href='".$results['url']."'>".$results['name']."</a> (".$results['short_withtag'].")<be>
```

The columns are `id`, `name`, `short`, `short_withtag` and `url`. The problem is, if I enter a keyword like pie (such a term existing in all of the rows) it will display only one search result. How do I make it display more than one?

Here is the query I use:

```sql
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM env
WHERE (`id` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`short` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`short_withtag` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`url` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Post the MySQL query you're using.

Comment: okay, I edited my post.

Comment: You need to get the results of the query into an array and then loop through adding to your $output variable each time.  You are currently just storing the first row of the result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get all rows into an array and then output them with a foreach loop.

You can do that like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM env
WHERE (`id` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`short` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`short_withtag` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`url` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());

// If query is successful
if ($result) {

    // Create an empty array to which we're going to put rows
    $dataForTheOutput = array();

    // Now push each row into the array
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        array_push($dataForTheOutput, $row);

    }

    // Now you can output data

    if (empty($dataForTheOutput)) {

        echo 'No results found';

    } else {

        // Using foreach loop display each row
        foreach ($dataForTheOutput as $component) {

            echo "Document ID: ".$component['id']."<br><a href='".$component['url']."'>".$component['name']."</a> (".$component['short_withtag'].")<br><span style='font-size: 12px;'>Bad search result? Try a different keyword</span>

        }

    }

}
```

Note that this is a quite obsolete and not very secure or maintainable way of doing things.